# disallow publish posts with special title

Tags: title, wp-title

I want to disallow some titles on wordpress and avoid publishing these posts.

example :
**"title : last news 8 hours ago"**

When this sentence is in the post title, I want disallow publish the post.
What's the solution?

Comment: Can you provide some context? What problem is this solving for you?

Answer (score 2):

The "easy" answer is: put a filter on it.

```php
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_function', 10, 3 );

function my_function( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status )
        return;

    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type )
        return; // restrict the filter to a specific post type

    $title = $post->post_title;

  $restricted_title = "title : last news 8 hours ago";

  if ($title == $restricted_title){ //if title matches unpublish
     wp_update_post(array(
        'ID'    =>  $post->ID,
        'post_status'   =>  'draft'
        ));
  }
}
```

But if the title is slightly different from the string you hardcode it will fail. My suggestion is to make a list of "restricted words" or phrases and check all of them. Like this:

```php
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_function', 10, 3 );

function my_function($new_status, $old_status, $post){

   if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status )
        return;

  if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type )
        return; // restrict the filter to a specific post type

  $title = $post->post_title;

  // Add restricted words or phrases separated by a semicolon

  $restricted_words = "word1;word2;word3";

  $restricted_words = explode(";", $restricted_words);
  foreach($restricted_words as $restricted_word){
    if (stristr( $title, $restricted_title)){ //if title matches unpublish
     wp_update_post(array(
        'ID'    =>  $post->ID,
        'post_status'   =>  'draft'
        ));
    }
  }
}
```

Anyway, my take on this is that you will never be 100% sure that these kind of filter works. You should really do it by hand.

Comment: tnx but... Unfortunately, this code does not work :(

Comment: I've tweaked the first solution I posted. What kind of problem do you encounter?

Comment: I used the same title in the post, and post published
There should be a draft
it's true?

Comment: the code should unpublish the post and put it in draft status. check you've transcribed correctly the third if condition (`if ($title == $restricted_title){ `)

Comment: sorry, I've tested it now and worked, but Only this sentence is supported, example : "title : last news 8 hours ago:new musics at weekend..." not detected !
How to use this code for any sentences using restricted_title?
and how to use for custom post type?

Comment: what happened? please help me :(

Comment: try using this condition: `strpos($title, $restricted_title) !== false`